# Add An Hour To TIME Datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time, dateadd

```
UPDATE Game
SET endTime = (SELECT DATEADD(hh, 1, startTime)
FROM GameInfo
WHERE Game.idGame = GameInfo.idGame);
```

I want to set the hours of endTime to be 1 hour later than the startTime, when I run this code I get the error:

```
ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
```

I believe this is because the startTime and endTime fields are both of datatype TIME, but I can't seem to find a similar function for TIME datatype?

```
UPDATE Game
SET endTime = (SELECT HOUR(startTime)+1
FROM GameInfo
WHERE Game.idGame = GameInfo.idGame);
```

Will almost work, in that it does increment the hours, but then it saves *just* the hours as a number (resulting in 00:00:19 etc. for all entries).

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Not as familiar with MySQL but in MSSQL you wouldn't need the SELECT statement. Just set it to the value of the function. `... SET endTime = DATEADD(hh,1,startTime)`

Comment: @tom . . . What database are you using?  The syntax suggests SQL Server, but the error suggests MySQL.  Also, why is the end time in a different table from the start time?

Comment: That's quite the interpretation of the error you are receiving.

Comment: The database is MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is: `DATE_ADD(startTime, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE g
    SET endTime = DATEADD(hour, 1, gi.startTime)
FROM Game g JOIN
     GameInfo gi
     ON g.idGame = gi.idGame;
```

Regardless of the database, I find it strange that the end time is in a different table from the start time.

Comment: I realised my names aren't too clear, the startTime is the time the game starts, and endTime is the time employees can go home (maybe changing it to departure time would be clearer).